# Creating a Deprecated/Obsolete behavior for methods in a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine has a popular open source JavaScript library which is quite well used in the community.  He is now going through a process of refactoring and applying best practices and conventions and is wanting to upper case all constructor functions.  So in the past where he may have defined a `chart` object, he now wants it to be called `Chart` to stick with convention.

Because the library is well used, he would rather warn devs when they use the old function names and eventually deprecate them.

I've recommended using a helper function :

```
var ObsoleteWithReplacement = function(replacementFunction, oldFnName, newFnName) {
    var wrapper = function() {
       if (console && console.warn) {
          console.warn("WARNING! Obsolete function called.  Function '" + oldFnName + "' has been deprecated, please use the new '" + newFnName + "' function instead!");
       }

        replacementFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    wrapper.prototype = replacementFunction.prototype;

    return wrapper;
}
```

Which could be called as follows : http://jsfiddle.net/rLNep/1/

Is this a good way to go about it?  Can you recommend a better way?

Comment: If you actually want to warn when a deprecated method is used then that approach seems fine to me. But IMHO it would be nicer to leave the code as it is and just change the documentation to make it clear the deprecated methods will be removed in a future release.

Comment: Remember to check for `console && console.warn` before `console.warn()`!

Comment: Thanks @PaulS. I've edited to include that now

Comment: I would use the `console` warn only as an optional option or at least show it only once per deprecated feature, to avoid slow down of the code. State the changes clearly in the documentation, and probably deliver two version, a migration version supporting the old code and new one only supporting the new convention.